# `.bashrc` is broken with `set -e` and can't login

Tags: bash, ssh

I broke my `.bashrc` by adding

```
set -e
```

at it's beginning (by mistake). Now I can't `ssh` to a machine. It just says

```
Connection to mymachine closed
```

Attempt to run any command like

```
ssh mymachine 'cat .bashrc'
```

has empty result.

```
ssh -t mymachine /bin/sh
```

also didn't work.

How else can it be fixed?

Comment: Tried `sftp` to update the file?

Comment: It also says "connection closed"; don't know why

Comment: I suppose then it doesn't use the internal subsystem, but runs another binary. Then I think you'll have to access the system using some other login method (e.g., a hypervisor console if a VM, start a shell as init from the bootloader, etc.), or login as another user that has sudo access so it can modify files in your home directory.

Comment: `ssh -t mymachine /bin/sh   also didn't work.`
Sure? Or did it just wait for your interactive input?

Answer (score 0):

This should work - `ssh <username@<host> "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f .bashrc'"`

Comment: This won’t work, as [explained by muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694741/bashrc-is-broken-with-set-e-and-cant-login/694784#comment1313533_694745).